# Arduino: Hardware SPI hangs, bit-bang does not

Tags: spi, atmega32u4

I'm using FastLED with a custom board built around the ATMega32u4. When I set it to use Software SPI, everything works fine, but when I use hardware SPI it just hangs whenever it tries to write out the data (FastLED.show()).

I originally mocked this up on an Arduino Pro Micro and it worked fine there. That makes me think that it's a hardware issue but, as I mentioned, SPI output *does* work, but only when bit-banged. Which really doesn't make much sense.

I tested this by also just using the built in SPI classes and I get the same thing. No luck with hardware SPI.

Anyone else ever see something like this?

The schematic of my circuit is below.

[image]

Comment: Have you checked SCK/MOSI with an oscilloscope to verify if some signal was sent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [ATmega32u4 datasheet](http://www.atmel.ch/Images/Atmel-7766-8-bit-AVR-ATmega16U4-32U4_%20Datasheet.pdf), section 17.2.1 (SPI / SS Pin Functionality / Master Mode:

> **If SS is configured as an input, it must be held high to ensure Master SPI operation.**

In your circuit, SS pin (#8 on package), also labeled as "**(SS/PCINT0) PB0**", is left unconnected.

Is it possible that PB0 is also configured as input somewhere in your program or libraries? In this case, it should be connected to Vcc.

Comment: YOU ARE MY FAVORITE PERSON RIGHT NOW!! I was testing on a Pro Micro and it just happened to have that pin connected to VCC through an LED and resistor. So, it made it work. pinMode(0, OUTPUT) made it all work again :) THANKS!

Comment: Just to add. Instead of connecting to vcc you can also just enable the internal pull-up resistor.

Comment: Or just configure the pin is OUTPUT which is the easiest way, and it enables you to use that pin for something else. That's probably the best option.